# How do I send form data and image data at the same time?

Tags: php, image, forms

I have a script that captures data in a form then writes it into a table. In the same script I also have a button for users to upload an image. The images and form MUST be linked to each other. e.g. if I create a recipe for chocolate cake, a user enters the ingredients and method and an image of the chocolate cake.

I'm guessing that would be done using a session however uploading an image is independent from submitting a form i.e. a user has to click a button to upload an image then submit to store the image into a folder and the path into a database and a separate submit button to write the form data into a database. In theory a user could upload 10 images and just one form. How do I ensure each image is linked to a single form? Is it possible to submit everything in one button click or is there another way to do this?

Link to tutorials would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you just make the file upload part of the same form?

Comment: @Mark Parnell I don't know how to do it! It doesn't make sense to me - click to upload an image, click to submit it and click to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct enctype

```
<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/youraction">
```